# ActiveMQ - encrypted passwords

Tags: java, activemq-classic

We are new to ActiveMQ and have read the [documentation on encrypted passwords](https://activemq.apache.org/encrypted-passwords).

The documentation talks about setting an environment variable (i.e. `ACTIVEMQ_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD`) to hold the encryption password, start ActiveMQ, and then unset that environment variable. But how will this work in the case of say a server restart? We can’t put that encryption password into any systemd service file.

Our security policies do not allow for the encryption passwords to remain in any configuration or settings files especially since the decrypt mechanism is also available on the same host via `bin/activemq` commands. So if a bad actor gets into the host he can get the secret and decrypt to get the real password.

Any alternatives?

Comment: I see that you posted this question on `#activemq` in Apache's Slack and sent an email to the users mailing list as well. Please use one support channel at a time. Posting to multiple is likely to duplicate effort across the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bootstrap problem with encrypting client-side secrets. There is no perfect solution, only acceptable trade-offs-- and this is not an ActiveMQ-specific issue. This challenge exists with all systems that want to encrypt client-side secrets, or password protect things like SSL certificates.

Option 1:

Set environment variable, start the process (in this case ActiveMQ), and then ideally unset the environment variable

Option 2:

Set the crypto password as a property in a config file and make it read-only to the user of the ActiveMQ process, and do not allow read access to any other users.